# Which is the best exit from metro Montparnasse to get to Avenue du Maine northbound direction?

Tags: transit, public-transport, paris, ratp

I will be taking the metro to Montparnasse - Bienvenüe on Saturday and I need to get to the Ibis hotel on Avenue du Maine. Which would be the best exit to take?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [French Wikipedia page on Montparnasse-Bienvenüe station](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montparnasse_-_Bienven%C3%BCe_%28m%C3%A9tro_de_Paris%29), there is exit 2 with a staircase (no elevators) alighting on Place Bienvenue leading onto Avenue du Maine.:

> #### Accès
>
> - Accès 1 : Porte Océane : accès direct dans la gare SNCF, escaliers et escalators
> - **Accès 2 : Place Bienvenüe : un escalier au 32, avenue du Maine**
> - [...]

The exit can be seen on [Google Street View](https://www.google.fr/maps/@48.842439,2.320518,3a,75y,312.52h,88.67t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1s2p5r18fRCPt57TwUMtrFPA!2e0!6m1!1e1) (look for the yellow `M` sign on top of the post). Assuming Google maps positioning is correct, [this would yield a total walking distance of 93m to your hotel](https://www.google.fr/maps/dir/Place+Bienven%C3%BCe,+75015+Paris/Hotel+ibis+Paris+Tour+Montparnasse+15%C3%A8me,+22+Avenue+du+Maine,+75015+Paris,+France/@48.8429682,2.3195233,18z/data=!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x47e670334e82113d:0x8d87b74a49d97608!2m2!1d2.3204991!2d48.8426564!1m5!1m1!1s0x47e670332f6c2517:0x324809bc4f0149cc!2m2!1d2.320246!2d48.843449).

Comment: Merci. I can see the exit on the street view.

Comment: Actually I hadn't thought of that. Do you have the link to the streetview, by any chance? :)

Comment: https://www.google.fr/maps/@48.842439,2.320518,3a,75y,312.52h,88.67t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1s2p5r18fRCPt57TwUMtrFPA!2e0!6m1!1e1 I'm not sure how to get a pretty URL. Do you think I should add "Ibis hotel" to the question title?

Comment: I don't think the fact that you are going to the Ibis hotel *per se* is relevant. What is is the fact that you want an exit heading north of Av. du Maine, imho.

Answer (score 5):

The RATP Android and iPhone apps have station surroundings maps where exit numbers are shown. There are also neighborhood maps in the station itself (for a station with multiple exits, there's usually one on each platform and one near a cluster of exits, but not one at every place where you need to choose between multiple exit corridors).

For some reason, the station surroundings maps on the website no longer show metro exits (they used to a few years ago). The website maps do show the exact location of bus stops, and connections to buses are clearly indicated in the station — but in your case I think the best exit doesn't lead to a bus stop.

A street map shows that your hotel is northwards of the station on Avenue du Main. To get to the north part of Avenue du Maine, take exit 2.

Note that this exit is on the metro 6 & 13 side of the station, the one at the end of the railroad tracks. It's a bit of a walk from the other end of the station where lines 4 and 12 stop.

Comment: Thank you for that extra information regarding which metro lines the exit is on.

Comment: Is it possible to get to the exit from where lines 4 and 12 stop? It sometimes seems as though some exits are not available when you use different metro lines at that station.

Comment: @camden_kid All exits are reachable from all lines. It's just that to reach this block of exits from lines 4 and 12, there's a long corridor.